# What is the Kronecker Product of two vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, kronecker-product

In my numerical methods course we got a homework problem that has a definition of a function

$\phi(x) = vec(M) - x \otimes x $

where $x\otimes x$ is the kronecker product of an n-vector and $ M $ is an $n\times n$ Matrix that is vectorized (flattened) in column-major by the $vec()$ operator.

I got confused as I thought the kronecker product would produce an $ n\times n$ matrix.
But according to the instructor it's a vector?

How would I compute the kronecker product of two vectors?
I thought it would be the entries of the first vector times the second vector appended in a matrix.

Thanks for anyone who can share some enlightenment. I tried to find some on Wikipedia but the examples there confirm my confusion.

I looked at this already: [Kronecker product and outer product confusion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/796709/kronecker-product-and-outer-product-confusion)

Thank you!

Comment: Just the usual kronecker product of matrices but taking $x$ to be a $1\times n$ matrix.

Comment: Hi @Rammus, thank you. Does this not result in a matrix with $ x_1x $ as the first column $ x_2x $ as the second .... $ x_nx $ as the last column?

Comment: No it should be a vector $(x_1 x_1, x_1 x_2, \dots, x_1 x_n, x_2 x_1, x_2 x_2, \dots,x_nx_n)$. Try having a look at the matrix Kronecker product again.

Comment: Thank you @Rammus ! As I feared I have misunderstood the kronecker product.

Comment: It might be better to put everything inside the vec function, i.e. $${\rm vec}(M) - x\otimes x \;=\; {\rm vec}(M-xx^T)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vector $x$ should be regarded as a matrix consisting of a single column. It then makes sense to consider the Kronecker product $x \otimes x$.

Comment: Hello @Bart Michels thanks for answering already. Doesn't this result in a Matrix $ x_1x, x_2x, x_3x....., x_nx.$ ?

Comment: Yes absolutely. Scalar multiples of $x$, stacked on top of each other.